# How to ensure that the right DLL's and modules are available when creating a Python PyQt executable on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, py2exe

I have a large PyQt5 GUI application which runs on Windows and Linux. However, there are many dependencies:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRunnable, QThreadPool, pyqtSignal, QDir, QItemSelectionModel, QDirIterator, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QDialog, QGridLayout,
                             QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton,
                             QSpinBox,  QDoubleSpinBox, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem,
                             QTabWidget, QLineEdit, QFrame, QFileDialog, QInputDialog,
                             QStyleFactory, QRadioButton, QLabel, QScrollArea, QButtonGroup, QScrollBar,
                             QAction, QActionGroup, QToolBar, QMessageBox, QMenu, QComboBox,
                             QVBoxLayout, QWidget,  QMainWindow, QProgressBar, QTextEdit,
                             QTreeView, QListView, QFileSystemModel, QAbstractItemView, QHeaderView)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPalette, QColor, QVector3D, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QBrush, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject, QUrl, pyqtProperty
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.console import ConsoleWidget
from pyqtgraph.widgets.RawImageWidget import RawImageWidget
from datetime import datetime
import argparse, time, glob
from copy import deepcopy
from functools import wraps
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import sys, os, itertools
import os.path
import json
from pprint import pformat
from inspect import getsourcefile
import pprint
import pathlib
import signal
import subprocess
from functools import partial
from collections import OrderedDict
import re, platform
from r_model.analyte_tags import analyte_tags
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from collections import defaultdict
import json
from shutil import copyfile
```

The `r_model` imports are from another Python project I created, which is symlinked to this project.

I tried using:

1. CxFreeze. The executable didn't run.
2. Tried fbs. The free version supports only Python 3.5 and 3.6. I'm using Python 3.7, so it didn't work.
3. Tried PyInstaller. Even with commandline arguments like `--onefile`, `--windowed`, `--hidden-import pyqtgraph`, but it still didn't work. It was possible to build an executable for a basic PyQt app, so it may just be a matter of resolving some of the imports to get this working on Windows.
   [image]
4. Tried `py2exe`, and when I run `python mysetup.py py2exe`, it says:

   614 missing Modules                                                                                                                                                                      ------------------                                                                                                                                                                     ? AppKit                              imported from pandas.io.clipboard                                                                                                                     ? Foundation                          imported from pandas.io.clipboard                                                                                                                    ? GraphicsView                        imported from pyqtgraph.SRTTransform, pyqtgraph.SRTTransform3D, pyqtgraph.widgets.GraphicsLayoutWidget, pyqtgraph.widgets.HistogramLUTWidget, pyqtgraph.widgets.MultiPlotWidget, pyqtgraph.widgets.PlotWidget, pyqtgraph.widgets.RemoteGraphicsView                                                                                         ? IPython                             imported from h5py, h5py.ipy_completer, matplotlib.backend_bases, matplotlib.pyplot, pandas.io.formats.printing                                      ? IPython.core                        imported from matplotlib.backend_bases                                                                                                               ? IPython.core.error                  imported from h5py.ipy_completer                                                                                                                     ? IPython.core.formatters             imported from pandas.io.formats.printing                                                                                                            ? IPython.core.interactiveshell       imported from h5py                                                                                                                                   ? IPython.core.pylabtools             imported from matplotlib.pyplot                                                                                                                      ? IPython.display                     imported from PIL.ImageShow                                                                                                                          ? IPython.utils                       imported from h5py.ipy_completer                                                                                                                     ? Numeric                             imported from numpy.distutils.system_info                                                                                                            ? OpenGL.NullFunctionError            imported from pyqtgraph.opengl.shaders                                                                                                               ? OpenGL.platform.PLATFORM            imported from OpenGL.GLU.glunurbs,   OpenGL.GLU.quadrics, OpenGL.GLU.tess, OpenGL.raw.GL._errors, OpenGL.raw.GL._types                                 ? OpenGL.platform.createBaseFunction  imported from OpenGL.GLU.quadrics, OpenGL.GLU.tess                                                                                                   ? OpenGL_accelerate                   imported from OpenGL.acceleratesupport                                                                                                               ? OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype     imported from OpenGL.arrays.arraydatatype,   OpenGL.arrays.arrayhelpers, OpenGL.converters                                                             ? OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker      imported from OpenGL.error                                                                                                                           ? OpenGL_accelerate.latebind          imported from OpenGL.latebind, OpenGL.wrapper                                                                                                        ? OpenGL_accelerate.vbo               imported from OpenGL.arrays.vbo                                                                                                                      ? OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper           imported from OpenGL.arrays.arrayhelpers,   OpenGL.converters, OpenGL.wrapper                                                                          ? PIL._imagingagg                     imported from -                                                                                                                                      ? PyQt4                               imported from pandas.io.clipboard                                                                                                                    ? PyQt4.QtGui                         imported from pandas.io.clipboard                                                                                                                    ? PyQt6                               imported from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg, matplotlib.backends.qt_compat, pyqtgraph.Qt,   pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.PlotItem.plotConfigTemplate_pyqt6,   pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ViewBox.axisCtrlTemplate_pyqt6,   pyqtgraph.imageview.ImageViewTemplate_pyqt6
   ...and so on...

I have Miniconda installed on Windows 10, and I've run all these commands using the Git Bash terminal. I've been able to get a simple PyQt app running using PyInstaller. But the DLL issues perplex me.

Is there no application that can automatically find all necessary DLL's and related modules to create a standalone executable? How does one go about solving these DLL and missing module issues?

Comment: I used PyInstaller Ver 4.7 on Win10 without problems on a PyQt5 project with pyqtgraph (ver 0.12.3). I'm on a regular Python install (ver 3.7 and 3.8) without virtual environment. However, my app does not use the ConsoleWidget. [This answer] hints that older versions of pyqtgraph (< 0.9.8) may not play nicely with PyInstaller.